# Android go to device all apps screen

Tags: android

I'm developing an app which requires to go to device all apps screen(screen after the home menu button click) from my app...

```
 Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
 startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
 startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 startActivity(startMain);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible.

First, there is no requirement that a home screen have an "all apps screen".

Second, there is no standard `Intent` structure to lead the user to an "all apps screen", even if one exists.

Comment: thank you for answering my question, but i want to check installed app from my app... that is the requirement, is there any other solution to do it..

Comment: @Samanalaya2: I do not know what "check installed app" means. If you mean that you want to check to see if a certain app was installed, use `PackageManager`.

Comment: no, i want to go to apps menu in the device.... simple here http://cdn3.pcadvisor.co.uk/cmsdata/features/3347925/Android_App_Menu.png